# For $1-r<|\theta|<1/2$, $|\frac{2r\sin{2\pi\theta}}{1-2r\cos{2\pi\theta}+r^2}-\frac{\cos\pi\theta}{\sin\pi\theta}|<C\frac{(1-r)^2}{|\theta|^3}$

Tags: calculus, inequality

> For $1-r<|\theta|<1/2$ show that
>   $$|\frac{2r\sin{2\pi\theta}}{1-2r\cos{2\pi\theta}+r^2}-\frac{\cos\pi\theta}{\sin\pi\theta}|<C\frac{(1-r)^2}{|\theta|^3}$$

This inequality shows that the integral of the left side on $[1-r,1/2]$ is bounded independent of $r$.

$|\frac{2r\sin{2\pi\theta}}{1-2r\cos{2\pi\theta}+r^2}-\frac{\cos\pi\theta}{\sin\pi\theta}|
=|\frac{4r\sin^2\pi\theta\cos\pi\theta-\cos\pi\theta+2r\cos2\pi\theta-4r\sin^2\pi\theta\cos\pi\theta-r^2\sin\pi\theta}{(1-2r\cos{2\pi\theta}+r^2)\sin\pi\theta}|
=|\frac{\cos\pi\theta-2r\cos\pi\theta+r^2\sin\pi\theta}{(1-2r\cos{2\pi\theta}+r^2)\sin\pi\theta}|$

Comment: A few questions: In which context did you encounter this inequality ? What integral are you referring to ? What is $C$ ?

Comment: some positive constant $C$. but $C$ should be independent of $r$ and $\theta$. The left quantity on the left side is the harmonic conjugate of $P_{r}(\theta)$. Using this inequality, we can represent the Hilbert transform as the integral form in the principal value sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a small trick: write $\frac{\cos \pi \theta}{\sin \pi \theta} = \frac{2\cos^2 \pi \theta}{\sin 2 \pi \theta}$ and use $1+ \cos 2 \pi \theta = 2\cos^2 \pi \theta.$ Now proceed by taking l.c.m, and all that.

Comment: Your trick yields nice computations indeed since $(r-1)^2$ factors out, but how do get the $\theta ^3$ in the denominator ?